# Cannot convert from java Double to java Date

Tags: java, date, double

I am having an issue with converting a double to a Java date object in the format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

I have tried to convert this double value to a long value then instanciate a Date object with the result, but I got errors saying that I cannot convert from double to long.

my timestamp double values are in this format:

1.511554592277516E9

Can anybody help me with this issue please, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Are you using primitives or `Double` and `Long` types?

Comment: Are you doing something like...counting seconds past the epoch or something?

Comment: I read the timestamp from a map object like this: double timestamp = (double) Map.get("ts"); then convert it to long using: long timestampLong = (long) timestamp; and finally create a date object like this: Date date = new Date(timestampLong); and it gives me a result like this one: Sun Jan 18 06:52:11 EST 1970

Comment: Why are you using a double to express time, anyway? It's not that it's forbidden, but you usually count the number of milliseconds ellapsed since a standard time. A long would be suitable for that. Are you using double because some system has such an imposition?

Comment: its not my choice, I recieve data in log files and its stored in that way: 1.511531688957562E9

Comment: @AnissChohra, thank you for answering the questions and providing more information. Rather than doing this in comments, it’s better to [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47701927/edit) and add the information there so new readers have everything in one place.

Comment: What is 1.5… supposed to represent in time? A count of years? Days? Seconds? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @BasilBourque, it’s 1.5**E9**, so 1_511_554_592.277_516, so no doubt seconds since the epoch with microsecond precision.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, I failed to notice the `E`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this floating point value is seconds past the Unix Epoch of 1 Jan 1970 0:00 GMT, this will provide a conversion to a `LocalDateTime` with that offset:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(
                Double.valueOf(1.511554592277516E9).longValue(), 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

I leave converting this to a `Date` as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I think I’d go for an `Instant` rather than a `LocalDateTime`. `Instant` too has an `ofEpochSecond` method, and it preserves the point on the timeline that the `long`represented. Conversion to `Date`, I would avoid it if I saw a way. The modern API is much nicer to work with.

Comment: @AnissChohra So your log file recorded a moment of one and a half seconds after the epoch reference date of the first moment of 1970? Difficult to believe. Are these log files taken from the [*Back to the Future*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future) movie?

Comment: @BasilBourque:  I'll give you a C- for effort, but the number is closer to 1,511,554,592.277516, which isn't one-and-a-half seconds away from 1970.

Answer (score 1):

Your floating-point value, `1.511554592277516E9`, no doubt denotes seconds since the epoch of January 1, 1970 at midnight UTC, with microsecond precision: 1 511 554 592 seconds and 277 516 microseconds (millionths of a second).

I suggest using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310, for this. It is much nicer to work with than the outdated `Date` class and friends, and also offers nanosecond precision (`Date` only has millisecond precision, so you would lose precision if converting into one). More specifically I will first create a `java.time.Instant` object (conversion to other date-time types will be easy, I’ll touch on one example at the end).

Getting the full precision through into an `Instant` requires a little thought. I played a little with `double` and `long`, but realized (1) `double` doesn’t have the full precision required, the nanoseconds will not be right (2) converting to a `long` holding the nanoseconds (not the only way, but certainly the easiest) will create a “year 2262 problem”, so if you are handling dates in a far future, it will not work. In any case, I think that the easy and safe solution is to use `BigDecimal` for the math required before feeding the numbers into an `Instant`.

```
    String secondsSinceEpoch = "1.511554592277516E9";
    BigDecimal decimalSeconds = new BigDecimal(secondsSinceEpoch);
    long seconds = decimalSeconds.longValue();
    long nanos = decimalSeconds.subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(seconds))
            .movePointRight(9)
            .longValueExact();
    Instant inst = Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds, nanos);
    System.out.println(inst);
```

This prints:

```
2017-11-24T20:16:32.277516Z
```

The printed date-time is in UTC. If the value is as expected, I should say it confirms that your floating-point value was indeed seconds since the epoch.

You requested a date-time in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. You will need to decide in which time zone you want the date-time. Date objects don’t have a format, so you will also need to get the format in a string. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(inst.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Vancouver")).format(formatter));
```

This prints

```
2017-11-24 12:16:32
```

You substitute your desired time zone, of course. `atZone()` converts the `Instant` into a `ZonedDateTime`, another often used class of `java.time`.

**EDIT**: In case you don’t want to bother with `BigDecimal`, you accept a slight inaccuracy and/or your receive your value as a double rather than a string, here’s an alternative in fewer lines of code:

```
    double secondsSinceEpoch = 1.511554592277516E9;
    long longSeconds = (long) secondsSinceEpoch;
    long micros = Math.round((secondsSinceEpoch - longSeconds) * 1_000_000);
    Instant inst = Instant.ofEpochSecond(longSeconds).plus(micros , ChronoUnit.MICROS);
```

In this particular case it gives exactly the same result, down to the nanosecond. I’m not sure whether with other inputs, the microseconds may end up inaccurate, but on the other hand, if you receive a double (not a string), there’s nothing you could do about that anyway.