# How to Convert a Jackson JavaTimeModule to Java Instant

Tags: java, jackson, java-time, jackson-modules

in Jackson `JavaTimeModule` java `time` objects are converted to timestamps in the for of `1421261297.356000000`, where the integer part is the number of seconds and the decimal part the number of nanoseconds of an `Instant`.

I want to convert this back to a `ZonedDateTime`, so the first step would be to convert this `timestamp string` into an `Instant`, but this format is completely out of standard and thus, there isn't any `java.time` method (that I know of) to convert `1421261297.356000000` to an `Instant` directly (without losing the nanosecond information).

I could do some `string` manipulation and extract the seconds and add the nanoseconds later, but it would be nice to not reinvent the wheel with this kind of boilerplate code, so my question is: **Are there any standard ways, methods or classes, to convert a Jackson `JavaTimeModule` timestamp string to an `Instant`?`**

Comment: Why don't you parse the JSON with Jackson in the first place? It will parse the value to an Instant for you.

Comment: Because I am using it on Android with `Retrofit` + `Moshi` on the App, and `Jersey` + `Jackson` on the webserver. I could change it to use `Jackson` with `Retrofit`, but I want to stick with `Moshi` for simplicity and better integration with `Retrofit`

Comment: Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27952472/6413377) already if it is any help?

Comment: This only works if I was using Jackson, but I am using Moshi.

Comment: This has been asked and answered a couple of times already. Please exercise your search skills. I have not heard of a standard method for it, but it is pretty straightforward to code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert from java Double to java Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701927/cannot-convert-from-java-double-to-java-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting epoch to ZonedDateTime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975195/converting-epoch-to-zoneddatetime-in-java) (the answers there do a little more than you ask for, but you can just take out the relevant part).

Comment: You could also configure Jackson to emit an ISO-8601 offset datetime.